# PHP - bind_result to array

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

I'm using a prepared statement for a query that returns multiple results, which I'd want to have in an array. But bind_result won't work with arrays, so this is how I do it:

```
$read_items = $db->stmt_init();
$read_items->prepare("SELECT item_id, item_name FROM items");
$read_items->execute();
$read_items->bind_result($var1, $var2);
while ($read_items->fetch()) {
  $item_id[] = $var1; 
  $item_name[] = $var2;
}
```

Is there clearer/better/more elegant way to put results into $item_id and $item_name arrays?

As it's visible from above, I'm using $var1 and $var2 like "intermediates" - and constantly have feeling there must be a better way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I can't take credit for it, but the [PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php#92505) has a nice solution (pasted verbatim):

```
<?php

// blah blah...
call_user_func_array(array($mysqli_stmt_object, "bind_result"), $byref_array_for_fields);

// returns a copy of a value
$copy = create_function('$a', 'return $a;');

$results = array();
while ($mysqli_stmt_object->fetch()) {
    // array_map will preserve keys when done here and this way
    $results[] = array_map($copy, $byref_array_for_fields);
}
```

Comment: Andy, thanks. I've also been through docs and comments, and tried the above code but it doesn't work for me. Could you illustrate how the above would apply to my concrete example? I'm rally having a bit of a hard time getting my head around this. Thanks.

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: PHP 5.3 and have full control over server so I can install whatever necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Argument unpacking](http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php#migration56.new-features.splat)(...) operator.

```
$results = array(null, null);
$read_items->bind_result(...$results);
while ($read_items->fetch()) {
  $item_id[] = $result[0]; 
  $item_name[] = $result[1];
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I really don't see the point of putting your item id's and item names in different arrays, you're breaking up a single object in two collections for ??? no reason . yes.

So, going back to this, what you should be doing is :

```
$items[$i]['var1']=$var1;

$items[$i]['var2']=$var2;
```

But this of course is still not very good.

The correct solution is to have a function that maps your mysqli result to an array so you can directly start working on that, whatever the query, here's mine - works in a few db's but not all are up to date at the moment :

```
function connectmysqldb($database,$host,$port,$user,$password){
    global $conn;
    $conn=mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database,$port);
    if (!$conn){ 
        die('Error: Could not connect: ' . mysqli_connect_error()); 
    } 
    return $conn;
}

function connectpgdb($database,$host,$port,$user,$password){
    $connectString = 'host=' . $host . ' port=' . $port . ' dbname=' . $database . ' user=' . $user . ' password=' . $password; 
    $conn = pg_connect ($connectString); 
        if (!$conn) 
        { 
        die('Error: Could not connect: ' . pg_last_error()); 
        } 
    return $conn;
}

function connectmssqldb($dbname,$host,$port,$uid,$pw){
    $connectionOptions = array("UID"=>$uid,"PWD"=>$pw);
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $host, $connectionOptions);
    if (!$conn) 
        { 
        die('Error: Could not connect: ' . print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true)); 
        } 
    return $conn;
}
function sqlec($query,$dbtype,$dbname,$host,$port,$uid,$pw){
    switch($dbtype){
            default:
                $res="Database Type not Recognized : $dbtype";
                break;

            case "mysql":
                global $conn;
                if(!isset($conn)){
                    $conn=connectmysqldb($dbname,$host,$port,$uid,$pw);
                }
                $clone=mysqli_multi_query($conn,$query); 
                if(!$clone){
                    die('Error:  ' . mysqli_error($conn)); 
                }else{
                    $clonearray=array();
                    $i=0;
                    if ($clone = mysqli_store_result($conn)) {
                        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($clone)){
                            $clonearray[$i]=$row;
                            $i++;
                        }
                        mysqli_free_result($clone);
                    }
                    $res=$clonearray;
                }
                break;

            case "postgres":
                $conn=connectpgdb($dbname,$host,$port,$uid,$pw);
                $clone=pg_query($conn,$query); 
                if (!$clone) 
                { 
                    die('Error:  ' . pg_last_error()); 
                }else{
                    $clonearray=array();
                    $i=0;
                    while ($row = pg_fetch_row($clone)) 
                        {
                        $count = count($row);
                        $y = 0;
                        while ($y < $count)
                            {
                            $c_row = current($row);
                            $clonearray[$i][pg_field_name($clone,$y)] = $c_row;
                            next($row);
                            $y = $y + 1;
                            }
                        $i = $i + 1;
                        }
                    pg_free_result($clone);
                    pg_close($conn);
                    $res=$clonearray;
                }
                break;

            case "mssql":
                $conn=connectmssqldb($dbname,$host,$port,$uid,$pw);
                $res=sqlsrv_query($conn,$query);
                if (!$res)
                {
                     die( "Error in statement execution.\n".print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
                }else{
                    $i=0;
                    $sqlsarray=array();
                    while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $res, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
                    {
                        if($i==0){
                        $arrk=array_keys($row);
                        }
                        $j=0;
                        while($j<count($arrk)){
                            $sqlsarray[$i][$arrk[$j]]=$row[$arrk[$j]];
                            $j++;
                        }
                        $i++;
                    }
                    $res=$sqlsarray;
                }
                break;
    }
    return $res;
}


function local_sqlec($query){
    global $db_server;
    global $db_db;
    global $db_port;
    global $db_username;
    global $db_password;
    return sqlec($query,"mysql",$db_db,$db_server,$db_port,$db_username,$db_password);
}
```

Which I use like this :

```
$r=local_sqlec("SELECT test1,test2 FROM test");
$i=0;
echo "last id =".($r[0]['test1'])."<br>";
echo "Row count =".($r[0]['test2'])."<br>";

while($i<$r[0]['test2']){
    echo "inserted id =".($r[0]['test1']+$i)."<br>";
    $i++;
}
```